# Принудительная отрисовка в v-for Vue

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Есть такой v-for

```
        <transition-group
            name="cc"
            tag="div"
            v-masonry
         item-selector=".grid-item"
         column-width=".grid-sizer"
         gutter=".gutter-sizer"
         horizontal-order="true"
         transition-duration="0"
         stagger="0">
        <div v-masonry-tile class="grid-item" v-for="(img, index) in viewImages" :key="img.id">
            <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
            <div class="gutter-sizer"></div>
            <article v-if="img.type === 2" v-html="img.text">
            </article>
            <a v-if="img.type === 1" @click="startGallery(index, $event)">
                <img-lazy :width="img.width" :height="img.height" :source="'/images/items/' + img.src"
                          :data-index="index" ref="thumbnails"></img-lazy>
            </a>
        </div>
    </transition-group>
```

viewImages используется как реактивный массив, при смене category в родителе я его чищу и заново помещаю все нужные элементы. НО, если div уже был отрисован, то анимация на него никак не применяется (логично, потому что он связан по key). Так вот вопрос, как заставить Vue заново отрисовать элемент, чтобы к нему применились анимации.

```
    .cc-enter {
    opacity: 0;
}

.cc-enter-to {
    opacity: 1;
}

.cc-enter-active {
    transition: opacity 1s ease;
    transition-delay: 1.1s;
}

.cc-leave {
    transform: scale(1);
}

.cc-leave-to {
    transform: scale(.1);
}

.cc-leave-active {
    transition: transform 1s ease;
}
```

Вот логика при смене категории, category является props

```
watch: {
        category: function (id) {
            this.viewImages = id === -1 ? this.images.slice() :
                this.images.filter(i => i.category_id === id);
        },
}
```

Comment: У вас изменяется `src` картинки при переключении категории? Если да, то можете попробовать сделать именно `src` значением для `key` вместо нынешнего `id`, который, судя по всему, остается неизменным.

Comment: Поменять key. Или key родителя.

Comment: src у конкретно того же div не изменяется. Я попробую, но сомневаюсь что это поможет.

Comment: Изменить key путем случайного числа мне кажется костылем

Comment: написать вот такой код: `this.viewImages = this.viewImages.map(item => item);`

Comment: Я говорил вот об этой части: `v-for="(img, index) in viewImages" :key="img.id"`, чтобы `:key="img.id"` стало `:key="img.src"`. Просто предположил, что, возможно, если цикл вам нужен для смены изображения, значит логично, что src атрибут будет всегда уникальным для отдельно взятого изображения. А насчет случайного числа - вполне себе рабочее решение, но, как мне кажется, практически всегда будет более рациональным способ.

Comment: Вариант с map не работает, так же не перерисовывается. Вариант с src так же ничего не меняет, src ведь не изменяется так же как и id объекта.